# Remove unmarked text?

Tags: notepad++

How do I remove or replace unmarked text in notepad++ (anything that isn't a 4 digit number in this case)?

I've marked the numbers I want to extract by searching **/d/d/d/d**, but there doesn't seem to be much I can do with marked text.  I can copy it, but that separates each number into a different line and I want to keep them on their original lines.

For example, I want to turn this:

```
John Molson, Montreal, Canada, No. 3, Lady Sherbrooke, 1817, 1818, 1825
John Molson & Sons, Montreal, Canada, 1819, 1820
Steamer Caledonia, 1817, 1818, 1820, 1822
```

Into this:

```
1817 1818 1825
1819 1820
1817 1818 1820 1822
```

It's seems strange to me that there aren't really any options for editing marked text.  I'm not sure what the point of it is.

Comment: Can you please post any code to show us what you have tried?

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what:  `\d{4}(*SKIP)(*F)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
            # a space
\d{4}       # 4 digits
(*SKIP)     # skip the match
(*F)        # and say it fails
|           # OR
.           # any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @GeoBurns: You're welcome, glad it helps.